# Boolean Algebra Distribution

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have some boolean algebra I preformed, but it does not appear to be right, and I am unable to justify to myself why.

$$F=(a+b+c)(a+b+d)$$
$$F'=(a'b'c')+(a'b'd')$$
$$F'=(a'b')(c'+d')$$
$$F=(a+b)(cd)$$

Yet if I let $a=c=d=0$ and $b=1$, then
$$(a+b+c)(a+b+d)=(0+1+0)(0+1+0)=(1)(1)=1$$
and for the simplified equation,
$$(a+b)(cd)=(0+1)(00)=(1)(0)=0$$
So it stands to reason that
$$(a+b+c)(a+b+d) \ne (a+b)(cd)$$
but it seems like this should work.  Would someone be able to explain where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When going from 
$$
F'=(a'b')(c'+d')
$$ to $F$, it's rather
$$
F=(a+b)\color{red}{+}cd.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The last step of your calculation is wrong:

$$\big((a'b')(c'+d')\big)'=(a'b')'+(c'+d')'=a+b+cd\;.$$